# Prolog program won't compute variable answer?

Tags: list, prolog, increment

This should be an easy fix, but I can't seem to tackle this, and it's getting frustrating. I've coded a program which computes or verifies that two lists are related because the elements of the second list are all incremented by one from the elements of the first list. This works when two lists are given, but not when it needs to compute a list.

Code is as follows:

```
inc([], []).
inc([X|XS],[Y|YS]) :- 
  Y =:= X+1,
  inc(XS,YS).
ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @CapelliC that only solves one direction.

Comment: @DanielLyons: I know, just suggested the (IMHO) simpler correction. BTW succ/2 it's about twice slower than arithmetic.

Comment: @CapelliC there are always tradeoffs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inc([],[]).
inc([X|XS],[Y|YS]) :-
  nonvar(X),
  Z is X + 1,
  Y = Z,
  inc(XS,YS), !.
inc([X|XS],[Y|YS]) :-
  nonvar(Y),
  Z is Y - 1,
  X = Z,
  inc(XS,YS), !.
```

Here we need to get a real computation for the addition, then attempt instantiation with =. The predicate had to be split to deal with the case where X was not instantiated, versus when Y wasn't. The `!` at the end of each is to prevent it from trying for more solutions after it has found one through one of the two similar paths.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had experimented with assigning a separate variable to be compared as well, but for some reason it was not working for me the way I wanted it to because of my =:= comparator. Does this mean that it is impossible to find a single predicate that could evaluate both a left and right handed expression?

Comment: This does not work if both arguments are variables (for example: `?- inc(X, Y).`). Consider using CLP(FD) constraints for a more general solution.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for your comments on my poor explanation. I deleted it so as not to further confuse. I speculated without giving it proper thought, for which I apologize. However, I think it's unfair to paint this as my having "...some pretty odd ideas about Prolog" under these limited circumstances. Further, it would be of more benefit for the op (and to me) if, based upon your obvious greater experience, provide a corrected explanation.

Comment: @mbratch I think the corrected explanation is contained in my answer below. I apologize for the wording in my comment; I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is essentially that `=:=/2` is for testing rather than establishing bindings, though `is/2` still doesn't really do what you want. For instance, while `2 is 1 + 1` is true, `2 is X+1` will not result in `X` being bound to 1, because `is/2` expects there to be just one variable or value on the left and one expression on the right, and it does not behave "relationally" like the rest of Prolog. If you want arithmetic that behaves this way, you should check out `clpfd`; looking at the complexity it adds is a good explanation for why things are the way they are.

Fortunately, you don't need all of arithmetic to solve your problem. The `succ/2` builtin will do exactly what you need, and bonus, you get a one line solution:

```
inc(X, Y) :- maplist(succ, X, Y).
```

In use:

```
?- inc([1,2,3], [2,3,4]).
true.

?- inc([1,2,3], X).
X = [2, 3, 4].

?- inc(X, [1,2,3]).
X = [0, 1, 2].
```

Your code also works fine if you use `succ/2` instead of `=:=/2`:

```
inc([], []).
inc([X|XS],[Y|YS]) :- 
  succ(X, Y),
  inc(XS,YS).
```

This must be the "easy fix" you suspected. :)

I'm not sure what @mbratch is referring to about there being "too many variables" for one predicate. I suspect this is a misunderstanding of Prolog on their part, perhaps a holdover from other languages where a function can return one value or something. There is no technical limitation here; predicates can take as many ground or nonground arguments and bind as many of them as you want; the limiting factor is your creativity.

Similarly, I don't think "asymmetry" is a meaningful concept here. It's quite normal to define predicates that have just a single instantiation pattern, but it's also normal and preferable to make predicates that are flexible about instantiation—you can't know ahead of time what uses may be needed in the future. You might think to yourself that an instantiation pattern that destroys information might preclude the inverse instantiation pattern, but in practice, frequently you can turn it into a generator instead.

To give a trite example, `append/3`'s name seems to imply this pattern:

```
 ?- append([1,2], [3,4], X).
 X = [1,2,3,4]
```

That's a perfectly good use, but so is:

```
?- append(X, Y, [1,2,3,4]).
```

This is a non-deterministic instantiation pattern and will produce five solutions:

```
X = [], Y = [1,2,3,4]
X = [1], Y = [2,3,4]
X = [1,2], Y = [3,4]
X = [1,2,3], Y = [4]
X = [1,2,3,4], Y = []
```

This seems to stand in contradiction to some of @mbratch's ideas, but there's no explicit testing for ground/nonground in the usual definition of `append/3`, because it isn't necessary, and likewise with the second calling pattern you get two "return values" from one input. [SWI source](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/lists.pl?show=src):

```
append([], L, L).
append([H|T], L, [H|R]) :-
    append(T, L, R).
```

**Edit**: Negative numbers. I forgot that `succ/2` is defined only on positive integers. We can apply @mbratch's technique and still get a tidy solution with the desired properties:

```
isucc(X, Y) :- var(X), X is Y-1.
isucc(X, Y) :- Y is X+1.

inc(X, Y) :- maplist(isucc, X, Y).
```

In action:

```
?- inc(X, [-1,2]).
X = [-2, 1] ;
false.
```

**Edit**: Using clp(fd) (via @mat):

```
fdsucc(X,Y) :- Y #= X + 1.
inc(X, Y) :- maplist(fdsucc, X, Y).
```

This generates even for the most general query:

```
?- inc(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [_G467],
Y = [_G476],
_G467+1#=_G476 ;
X = [_G610, _G613],
Y = [_G622, _G625],
_G610+1#=_G622,
_G613+1#=_G625 ;
X = [_G753, _G756, _G759],
Y = [_G768, _G771, _G774],
_G753+1#=_G768,
_G756+1#=_G771,
_G759+1#=_G774 
...
```

The utility of this is questionable, but presumably since you're using clp(fd) you'll eventually impose other constraints and get something useful.

Comment: Your code does not work for example for the most general query: `?- inc(X, Y).`. It does if you use CLP(FD).

Comment: I tried the `maplist` and `succ` based solutions on `inc(X,[0,3]).` and it failed. However, the solution that I offered without using `succ` or `maplist` worked and yielded `X = [-1,2]`.

Comment: I just tried `inc([1,2],[2,3]).` on the `maplist/isucc` version and it came back `no`. It does well on the `inc(X,[...]).` and `inc([...],Y).` cases though.

Comment: @mbratch That's because neither 1 nor 2 passes `var/1`. See if you can fix it.

Comment: Just remove `var(Y), ` from your second `isucc`. So it becomes: `isucc(X, Y) :- Y is X+1.` I think that takes care of it. Nice.